# Netbeans Watch Variables

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I am trying to find where a variable changes its value when I'm running my Java project in Netbeans. It changes from false to true, which should not be happening. There are several classes that could be changing the variable and I need to find exactly which one and where.

I'd like to add a watch to the variable that's changing so that when I run the debugger I can step through and see exactly when it changes, but I don't know how to do this properly.

I opened the class that starts the process of the variable change (the change happens when I change tabs on a screen) and created a watch for `this.toolbar.deletebutton.isEnabled()`. When the debugger steps into another class that variable is no longer available in the watch, it is still being edited but it's not called the same thing, and this changes many times as the program is running.

So how do I make a watch that will track the variable throughout the classes as the program is running?